# react-native error Can't find variable: styles

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to React-native . I'm trying to style a view element in my component, and when attempting to apply style tag , I'm getting the following error:

NOTE :
**My style tag in separate js file**

In styles.js

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

    const DEVICE_WIDTH= Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const DEVICE_HEIGHT= Dimensions.get('window').height;

    export default {
       container:{
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          flex:1 ,
          width: DEVICE_WIDTH,
          height: DEVICE_HEIGHT,
         }
    };
```

in Main.js file

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Router,Scene,Actions} from "react-native-router-flux";
import {View} from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles.js'

class Main extends Component{

render(){
    return(
            <View style={styles.container} >
                    <Text>
                        Hello pages
                    </Text>
            </View>

    );
  }
}

 export default Main;
```

Error screen:
[image: error]

Comment: Check if styles.js is in the same directory as of main.js. May be you have not specified file path correctly. and import styles from './styles' no need to wirte .js. Also your file name is style.js while you are importing styles.js(an extra 's' in the name)

Comment: both are the files are in same directory and the file was styles I edit the file name in question sections

Comment: ok . I will take your advice for question and thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to use StyleSheet.create like this

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(249, 250, 252)',
  },
})
```

also check if you are importing styles.js correctly and you also dont need to put .js in import like this

```
import styles from './styles'
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue was solved by correcting spelling of style applied,
from

```
 <View style={style.subcontainer}>,
```

to

```
 <View style={styles.subcontainer}>,
```

because I have

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"

  },
```

Comment: I did that, but the error persits